# using GrailsApplication in service

Tags: grails

So I have done a bunch of research on using grailsApplication in services but none of them seem to work (2.4.4)

here's how i'm trying to use it

```
class AddressLookupService {

    def grailsApplication

    def addressLookup(address1, address2, city, state, zip){
        def addressValidationErrors = verifyAddress(
            grailsApplication.config.uspsUserId,
            address1, address2, city, state, zip, '')
        return addressValidationErrors.errDescription
    }
}
```

and the error I'm getting

`Cannot get property 'config' on null object`

Comment: Is the service inside `grails-app/service`?

Comment: Check out [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28007893/160313) for a similar question. Make sure `def grailsApplication` is a class-scope variable (field) and not inside a method or other scope that's not visible to Spring. Also try deleting your `target` directory and running `grails compile` to force a full clean and recompile - you might just be out of sync.

Comment: @dmahapatro yes the service is inside grails-app/services

Comment: @BurtBeckwith grailsApplication is a class scope variable (field).  I also did a `grails clean` followed by `grails refresh-dependencies` and it still didn't work.  I've updated my question showing the entire class

Comment: Ok, next question would be how/where is the service method getting invoked? test? application runtime?

Comment: @dmahapatro during run-app

Answer (score 1):

You can import  [Holders](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) class in service as

`import grails.util.Holders as H` and then use this holder as 
`H.grailsApplication?.config?.uspsUserId`

Comment: or just `H.config.uspsUserId`

Comment: Nope, avoid the Holders class. Use dependency _injection_

Comment: Works as expected, though Igor is right about accessing the config, that way is shorter.